# How to align Buttons

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Buttons are lying horizontally one after the other. I need to know how to make them appear on the screen vertically. I tried adding SwingConstants.xxxx. Then item.SwingConstants.xxx got the horizontal alignment error. Any help is appreciated. (want to stick to this style of program)

```java
import java.awt. * ;
import java.awt.event. * ;
import javax.swing. * ;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Class_GUI_4 extends JFrame {
  private JTextField tf; // textfield
  private JCheckBox b1; // button 1
  private JCheckBox b2; // button2
  public Class_GUI_4() {
    super("TITLE");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    tf = new JTextField("A testing Sentence", 20);
    tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    add(tf);

    b1 = new JCheckBox("Bold");
    b2 = new JCheckBox("Italic");
    add(b1);
    add(b2);

    thehandler handler = new thehandler();
    b1.addItemListener(handler);
    b2.addItemListener(handler);
  }

  private class thehandler implements ItemListener {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
      Font font = null;
      if (b1.isSelected() && b2.isSelected()) font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
      else if (b1.isSelected()) font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
      else if (b2.isSelected()) font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
      else font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
      tf.setFont(font);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class_GUI_4 gui = new Class_GUI_4();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setSize(200, 350);
    gui.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to make them come on screen vertically?

Try with [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html)

```
setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

instead of [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) in this case that arranges components in a directional flow, much like lines of text in a paragraph.

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

It's worth reading about [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

[image]

---

**Don't** use `GridLayout` in this case that adds the components in equal size as shown below:

[image]

---

Instead you can try with [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html). Read more about [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Sample code: (Change the height as per your requirement in percentage)

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

//Set the margin between components top, left, bottom, right
//gc.insets=new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

tf = new JTextField("A testing Sentence", 20);
tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));

gc.gridx = 0; // 1st row
gc.gridy = 0; // 1st column
gc.weighty = 0.9; // 90%
add(tf, gc);

b1 = new JCheckBox("Bold");
b2 = new JCheckBox("Italic");
gc.gridy = 1; // 2nd column
gc.weighty = 0.05;// 5%
add(b1, gc);

gc.gridy = 2; // 3rd column
gc.weighty = 0.05;// 5%
add(b2, gc);
```

[image]

Comment: I tried both and observed, thank u all for such fast and rapid response. can u tell more please how to shrink the size of textfields'  (height) it's taking whole screen and leaving little space at the end for two check boxes.! kindly leave a positive score on thread so i can get enough repo to like the multiple answers after ticking the main answer. again thanks.... to all.@Braj

Comment: Try last option and change the height as per your requirement in percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to format your UI Component ,you can choose between  the Layout that will help you making a vertical alignement which are [Grid Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html)  or [Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the layout manager you are using is FlowLayout().

```
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Use GridLayout manager instead by replacing the code with:

```
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3)
```

Comment: Look at my post that how it will look like when used `GridLayout`?

Comment: Correct, but the question was how to align them vertically, and GridLayout does the job too.

Comment: So are you OK with this look and feel.